# How to respond without html in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Easy question perhaps.

Okay, I have a post to my page and need to respond with one string.

in php, you could simply do something like this:

```
<?php
die ("test");
```

then you can place this page on a webserver and access it like this:

```
localhost/test.php
```

so, I need to do exact same thing in c#.

When I try to respond with:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("test");
        Response.End();
    }
```

I'm getting: `"<html><head><style type="text/css"></style></head><body>test</body></html>"`
as a response.

How can I make asp.net to just return exact response, without html?

I know that I probably missing some basic knowledge, but cannot find anything online.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue; With VS2010 starting a fresh out of the box "ASP.NET Web Application" and using your code produces as expected: only "test".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure in your `*.aspx` file, at the top you have `AutoEventWireup="true"`, if it's false (or not there?) your `Page_Load` event handler will not be called.

Also, make sure you compiled your page.

Another suggestion is to use a `Generic Handler` (ie `*.ashx`), these do not use the typical webforms lifecycle and might be better suited to what you're doing.

Comment: Let me try ashx and see what will happen.

Comment: keep in mind you will use `context.Response` (or whatever the parameter name is) instead of plain `Response`.

Comment: Probably a noob mistake, but my .aspx page had basic skeleton <html> tags that I didn't think to remove.  Once these were gone, my response did not include them (imagine that!) and my json string no longer had a parsing error.

Answer (score 12):

You can clear the previous response buffer and write your new output.

```
Response.Clear(); // clear response buffer
Response.Write("test"); // write your new text
Response.End(); // end the response so it is sent to the client
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it doesn't help. Maybe I need to change the way how I'm calling my script? Currently I'm creating a website with both aspx and cs files.

Comment: Try changing the event you're attaching to - try `Page_PreInit` instead.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        Response.Write("test");
        Response.End(); 

    }
```

Comment: Doesn't help. still the same.

Comment: @user194076 this should be the answer, i also added Response.Clear() before ContentType just to make sure :P

Answer (score 3):

For me it only Generates actual text in response.write(); statement. I am uploading the complete code for clarity.

Visual Studio: 2010

**Code Behind:**

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("I CAN ONLY SEE THIS NO OTHER HTML TAG IS INCLUDED");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**OUTPUT & HTML Source:**

I CAN ONLY SEE THIS NO OTHER HTML TAG IS INCLUDED

I am getting the desired result. I have tried this code with Master-Page also i get the same result.

Please make sure your **AutoEventWireup="true"** if i turn this false then HTML SOURCE changes to this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Default2.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZGivF0fgbeE6VebNR51MYSu3yJdsZ9DwEtIPDBVRf4Vy" />
</div>

    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer suggests above, you need `AutoEventWireup="true"` as well as `Response.End()` in code behind.